# mysql connector for building POCO library

Tags: c++, mysql, build, mysql-connector, poco-libraries

Which MySQL connector package should I download, in order to build POCO C++ library ? There are two options at 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/

1. Connector/C++
2. Connector/C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the C++ MySQL Connector.